# Cordova Firebase Authentication Fails for Android 7.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a Cordova app that uses Firebase Authentication services for Facebook, Twitter, and Google. My code is based on this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

It has been working fine up to this point, except this week I noticed that when targeting an emulator/device with the new Android 7.0.0 OS, Firebase authentication for all 3 providers fails after the auth redirect back to the app. (The redirect works correctly, but the Auth.$onAuthStateChanged method is never called).

I verified that my auth works on an emulator running Android 4.4 (API 19) but not on 7.0.0 (API 24).

```js
// provider == 'facebook' or 'twitter' or 'google'

Auth.$signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function(authData) {
  // User successfully logged in
  // check $onAuthStateChanged below
}).catch(function(error) {
  if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
    $scope.loading = true;
    Auth.$signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(authData) {
      // User successfully logged in
      // check $onAuthStateChanged below
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // This one didn't work either...
      $scope.err = error;
      $scope.loading = false;
    });
  } else {
    // Another error occurred
    $scope.err = error;
    $scope.loading = false;
  }
});

Auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(authData) {
  // User successfully logged in
  if (authData) {
    $scope.loading = false;
  }
});
```

Is there a change I need to make to my auth code to support Android 7.0.0?

Comment: Did you test this on an actual device running 7.0.0?

Comment: Yes, and it has the same problem. The redirect back to the app happens, but the auth state never changes. I've narrowed it down to the change from Deep Links to Android App Links in Android 6.0. https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html